# HTTP error. Receiving HTML instead of JSON. How do I get JSON?

Tags: json, node.js, angular, http

I'm working with HTTP requests on a MEAN stack.

When I'm developing on localhost, all of the requests work.

But, when I try to do the same requests via production, they do not work.

Here's the error I am getting when trying to POST...

```
ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

I'm also getting an error with GET after sending my POST request.

```
GET http://atozinsurance.herokuapp.com/post 503 (Service Unavailable)
```

I know this means I'm receiving HTML instead of JSON. What am I doing wrong in my code to be requesting HTML?

Here is my NodeJS route for posts

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var Post = require('../models/post');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Post.find()
    .exec(function(err, posts){
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
          title: 'An error occurred',
          error: err
        });
      }
      res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Success',
        obj: posts
      });
    });
});

// router.use('/', function (req, res, next) {
//   jwt.verify(req.query.token, 'secret', function (err, decoded) {
//     if (err) {
//       return res.status(401).json({
//         title: 'Not Authenticated',
//         error: err
//       });
//     }
//     next();
//   })
// });

router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
  const post = new Post({
    title: req.body.title,
    content: req.body.content,
    date: req.body.date
  });
  post.save(function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        title: 'An error occured',
        error: err
      });
    }
    res.status(201).json({
      message: 'Post saved',
      obj: result
    });
  });
});

router.patch('/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  Post.findById(req.params.id, function (err, post) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        title: 'An error occurred',
        error: err
      });
    }
    if (!post) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        title: 'No Post Found!',
        error: {message: 'Post not found'}
      });
    }
    post.title = req.body.title;
    post.content = req.body.content;
    post.date = req.body.date;
    post.save(function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
          title: 'An error occurred',
          error: err
        });
      }
      res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Updated post',
        obj: result
      });
    });
  });
});

router.delete('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  Post.findById(req.params.id, function (err, post) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        title: 'An error occurred',
        error: err
      });
    }
    if (!post) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        title: 'No Post Found!',
        error: {post: 'Post not found'}
      });
    }
    post.remove(function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
          title: 'An error occurred',
          error: err
        });
      }
      res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Deleted post',
        obj: result
      });
    });
  });
});



module.exports = router;
```

And here is my service that is sending the requests via Angular.

```
import { Http, Response, Headers } from "@angular/http";
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

import { Post } from "./blog.model";

@Injectable()
export class PostService {
  private posts: Post[] = [];
  inputEditMessage = new EventEmitter<Post>();
  url = 'http://atozinsurance.herokuapp.com/post';
  devUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/post/';

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  addPost(post: Post) {
    const body = JSON.stringify(post);
    const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    // const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    //   ? '?token=' + localStorage.getItem('token')
    //   : '';
    return this.http.post(this.url, body, {headers: headers})
      .map((response: Response) => {
        const result = response.json();
        const post = new Post(
          result.obj.title,
          result.obj.content,
          result.obj.date,
          result.obj._id);
        this.posts.push(post);
        return post;
      })
      .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
  }

  getPosts() {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
      .map((response: Response) => {
        const posts = response.json().obj;
        let transformedPosts: Post[] = [];
        for (let post of posts) {
          transformedPosts.push(new Post(
            post.title,
            post.content,
            post.date,
            post._id)
          );
        }
        this.posts = transformedPosts;
        return transformedPosts;
      })
      .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
  }

  editPost(post: Post) {
    this.inputEditMessage.emit(post);
  }

  updatePost(post: Post) {
    const body = JSON.stringify(post);
    const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
      ? '?token=' + localStorage.getItem('token')
      : '';
    return this.http.patch(this.url + '/' + post.postId + token, body, {headers: headers})
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
  }

  deletePost(post: Post) {
    this.posts.splice(this.posts.indexOf(post), 1);
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
      ? '?token=' + localStorage.getItem('token')
      : '';
    return this.http.delete(this.url + '/' + post.postId + token)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
  }
}
```

As I stated before, with localhost (called devUrl) it works fine. But when I switch to url or production mode, it fails.

Anyone know where the bug is?

EDIT *** This is the HTML error I am receiving.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Application Error</title>
        <style media="screen">
          html,body,iframe {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }
          html,body {
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
          }
          iframe {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border: 0;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <iframe src="//www.herokucdn.com/error-pages/application-error.html"></iframe>
      </body>
    </html>
```

EDIT ***

Here is my server.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const appRoutes = require('./routes/app');
const mailRoutes = require('./routes/mail');
const userRoutes = require('./routes/user');
const postRoutes = require('./routes/post');



const app = express();
const uristring =
  process.env.MONGOLAB_URI ||
  process.env.MONGOHQ_URL ||
  'localhost:27017/atoz';

mongoose.connect(uristring, function (err, res) {
  if (err) {
    console.log ('ERROR connecting to: ' + uristring + '. ' + err);
  } else {
    console.log ('Succeeded connecting to: ' + uristring);
  }
});

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, './dist'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './dist')));

app.use(function (req,res,next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  next();

});

app.use('/user', userRoutes);
app.use('/post', postRoutes);
app.use('/mail', mailRoutes);
app.use('/', appRoutes);

//catch 404 and forward error handler
app.use('*', appRoutes);

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);

module.exports = app;
```

EDIT ***
Here is the error I am receiving from heroku logs

```
at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/post" host=atozinsurance.herokuapp.com request_id=c4e340d3-8ee3-4c2f-ae12-e56e7439c0f1 fwd="68.111.238.205" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
Macs-MacBook-Pro-2:atoz-app joncorrin$
```

Comment: Maybe the endpoint at production is failing and returning a HTML error page instead of JSON?

Comment: Thats very possible. I did an API check with Postman and I added the HTML error Im receiving in the above.

Comment: will you please also post the root js file (index.js / server.js / app.js)

Comment: Just added server.js Vivek!

Comment: So, if the code works fine in dev, but not in production, it is an indicator that the problem is in the environment and not in the code itself. What are the differences between the dev and prod environments? Other applications/features of the app work well in prod or there are none other?

Comment: I just tried it with my contact feature that uses nodemailer. The POST was rejected because there was an authorization error from google. That error was explained in heroku logs. The console errors I receive from POST on blog posts stated above are the same console errors. JSON at position 0 and Service unavailable. When I run heroku logs on a POST request with the blog posts, it only says request timeout.

Comment: All I do to switch from dev to production is change devUrl to url in my angular service.

Comment: Scratch that, I'm getting the same error when I try to do a user sign in. Its a 503 error and causes a timeout via heroku

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this issue. You're receiving HTML from Heroku. The first character in HTML is a < which explains why it is definitely not JSON.

MY SOLUTION: 
I did not set my environment variable for MONGOLAB_URL. Therefor heroku could not connect to the database correctly and the request was timing out.

Set it as MongLab addon and worked perfectly.